# How to get last added layer in pyqgis?

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3

Can we find last added layer in pyqgis? I use `Data Source Manager | Delimited Text` at the end of the process it creates a layer and adds it layers panel:

[image]

However, I can not know what the `Layer Name` is and I have to know that what it is.